# MySQL causes 100% disk utilization

Tags: mysql, disk, utilization

I'm running an MySQL (InnoDB) Database with XAMPP. I made many different, expensive queries on a table (~1,1M rows) and canceled them severel times because the took a very long time...

If I'm starting MySQL right now, the disk utilization is instantly on 100% and doesn't decrease. Is it possible, that the previous canceled queries got queued and executed right now in the background?

`show processlist;` displays no running process...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Part of mysql-error.log

```
2016-09-09 10:04:56 2068 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
2016-09-09 10:04:56 2068 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-09-09 10:04:56 3478  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 426031, 90941 rows to undo
```

This might be the problem... but how to solve it?

Comment: Are you running this on actual machine or on a VM?  How much RAM is being allocated, and how much memory does MySQL use up when it spikes?  "Disk usage" probably isn't what you mean, but rather CPU usage.

Comment: By "disk usage" are you referring to space on the volume, or to disk i/o utilization? How exactly are you determining that "disk usage" is 100%? If the volume is "full" and there is no more disk space, that's a problem. You'd need to figure out what is taking up the space, and see if you can recover any of it. If MySQL binary logging is enabled, one quick and dirty thing to do is to clear out old log files (assuming those are no long required for replication or recovery), e.g. `PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY`.

Comment: Just 35MB RAM usage and most of the time nearly 0% CPU usage. Running this on my actual (strong) machine. 
Usage in my case means utilization. Enough space availible ;-)

Comment: Adding to the logging issue, if long query logging is enabled and you are running them, you can use literally gigabytes of disk space with the log itself.  Try truncating the mysql-slow.log, mysql.err and mysql.log (AFTER checking them for errors, of course).

Comment: sorry for the wrong expression. I mean utilization and not usage. Mysql is not using that much space on my disk ;-) It 'only' stresses my HDD with many I/Os ...

Answer (score 0):

A little work-around:

1. export database
2. delete this database
3. reset all mysql-settings
4. import database

Better solutions are welcome! =)